# How to use different version of gnuplot

Tags: centos, octave

I am running octave 4.2.2 on centOs 6 , and I've encountered some issue plotting graphs:

```
error: graphics_toolkit: gnuplot version too old.
```

some questions on this site suggeted installing  gnuplot version 4.4 instead of 4.2 (the centOs 6 default).
I installed it and now I have 2 gnuplot apps under /usr/bin/ , **gnuplot** & **gnuplot44**.
my question is, how to make octave to use **gnuplot44** and not **gnuplot** ?
I've tried the next steps:

```
octave:2> register_graphics_toolkit('gnuplot44')
octave:3> available_graphics_toolkits
ans = 
{
  [1,1] = gnuplot
  [1,2] = gnuplot44
}
octave:4> graphics_toolkit('gnuplot44')
error: feval: function '__init_gnuplot44__' not found
error: called from
    graphics_toolkit at line 91 column 5
```

I have also tried with full path and got the same result:

```
 octave:4> register_graphics_toolkit('/usr/bin/gnuplot44')
octave:5> available_graphics_toolkits
ans = 
{
  [1,1] = /usr/bin/gnuplot44
  [1,2] = gnuplot
  [1,3] = gnuplot44
}
octave:6> graphics_toolkit('/usr/bin/gnuplot44')
error: feval: function '__init_/usr/bin/gnuplot44__' not found
error: called from
    graphics_toolkit at line 91 column 5
```

How can I overcome this issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`gnuplot_binary`](https://octave.sourceforge.io/octave/function/gnuplot_binary.html) :

```
gnuplot_binary('gnuplot44');
```